# Hyperlink behaves like label when adding second hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have an issue with HTML and CSS.
Below is a block of HTML.  When I only have the first  (the Login area), then it looks okay.  As soon as I add the second  the first hyperlink (Login) becomes not clickable.  Meaning that the cursor does not change to a hand and I can click on it, and it behaves like a label.

HTML:

```
    <div id="login" align="right" style="position:relative;top:-25px">
        <span>
            <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Pages/Login.aspx">Login</a>&nbsp
        </span>
    </div>
    <div align="right" style="position:relative;top:-41px;right:-50px">
        <span>
            <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Default.aspx">Logout</a>&nbsp
        </span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.LoginHyperlink
{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFCC;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because the second `div` is on top. I've created a Fiddle to show you, and added borders.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bZW8/)

You need to change the positioning, or the width. The width is currently going to 100%.

In this second fiddle, I've cleaned up the CSS a bit. Couple things. Inline styling is not a great idea. If we move the styling to a CSS file, it'll be easier to replicate and edit later. Also, using `align=` is not good. We should do all styling with CSS. Take a look at the new Fiddle and tell me if it is what you need.

HTML

```
<div id="login">
    <span>
        <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Pages/Login.aspx">Login</a>&nbsp
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>
        <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Default.aspx">Logout</a>&nbsp
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.LoginHyperlink {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div {
    float:right;
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bZW8/1/)

Comment: Patrolling everywhere :p haahaaaaha

Comment: Nothing, just very active in answer :D

Comment: Just trying to help. If you like the answers, feel free to +1 'em.

Comment: You owe me one then :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually both the links are working, the only problem is with the positioning you are doing.

Try

```
<div id="login" align="right" >
    <span>
        <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Pages/Login.aspx">Login</a>&nbsp
    </span>
</div>
<div align="right" >
    <span>
        <a class="LoginHyperlink" href="../Default.aspx">Logout</a>&nbsp
    </span>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P86R2/1/)